# Grafana : how to use Geomap lookup with cities

Tags: prometheus, grafana, geomap

I am using grafana with Prometheus as datasource (this last one sends me a list of cities - no coords, only city names) and I am using the geomap Visualizations but there are only 3 options in Gazetteer option : Countries, USA States and Airports.

I would like to match with cities in the world .. Is there a way to add cities in Gazetteer option ??

[geomap](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yje5v.png)

Answer (score 0):

It doesn’t make sense to have cities lookup (city names are not unique very often). Let’s say you have city with the name London - where do you place it on the map? [There are 29 places around the world called London.](https://www.wanderlust.co.uk/content/londons-around-the-world/)

Comment: I didn't think about it ... then maybe countries with cities :/ ... like London, United Kingdom. I don't know if it's possible....

Comment: Or London, UK/London, GB/London, GBR/.... a lot of combinations and possible inputs, so that lookup table will huge. It doesn't make sense.